# Retain menu item animation after refresh?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-animation, android-menu

I have a menu item in my `ActionBar` that kicks off an `AsyncTask` and while the task is running I have the menu item animating to show progress.  I am also refreshing the animation on every selection of my `ListView` because the menu items change depending on which item is clicked.  I have everything working except I have a check to see if the `AsyncTask` is running, in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and to restart the animation (because when redrawing the menu the animation stops).  Not sure if there is a better way to do this though.

This is the code I have to checks if the `AsyncTask` is running and restart the animation for the one menu item:

Note: elsewhere in the code I'm using this to reset the menu, if it matters:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();


public class MyFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    private MenuItem refreshItem;
    private AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> fi;
    private MenuItem refreshItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

        fi = new FetchItems(activity, null);
        fi.execute(); //this actually happen when the menu item is selected but I put here for this question
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        if (fi != null && fi.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
        {
            if (refreshItem != null && refreshItem.getActionView() != null)
            {   
                refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                refreshItem.setActionView(null);

                this.StartAnimation();
            }
        }
        else
            refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.filter);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
          StartAnimation();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused)
        {
            if (refreshItem != null && refreshItem.getActionView() != null) 
            {
                refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                refreshItem.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartAnimation() {
       final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       final ImageView ivRefresh = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_view, null);

       final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.refresh);
       ivRefresh.startAnimation(rotation);
       refreshItem.setActionView(ivRefresh);
    }
}
```

refresh.xml

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000" 
/>
```

Comment: Could you please add `anim/refresh.xml`?

Comment: @sriramramani updated the OP with refresh.xml

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I created a function called StopAnimation:

```
private void StopAnimation()
{
    if (refreshItem != null && refreshItem.getActionView() != null) 
    {
        refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
        refreshItem.setActionView(null);
    }
}
```

Then in `onCreateOptionsMenu` I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    StopAnimation();

    refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.filter);

    if (fi != null && fi.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
            this.StartAnimation();

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```